# In android Studio Alt+Enter or Control+I for Implementation is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, overriding

I update android studio with version 3.4. it was working fine but the problem with of implementation, for example, I have just used an interface in class and after that, I have to click interface for method implementation and its show a method's popup and I click all the method for Implementation but it's not integrated on my project here I show the screen below:

Here: I Implement the Interface

[image]

after that, it shows the red line error and asks for implement methods

[image]

And, after its click on implement method and show the next popup and I click ok but it's not implemented 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in the settings if SDK and the API versions are the same.